# could not load hiredis extension (undefined symbol: redisReaderFree)

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, redis

I'm trying to require hiredis in irb and it's already sending me an error:

```
irb(main):001:0> require "hiredis"
WARNING: could not load hiredis extension, using (slower) pure Ruby implementation.
=> true
irb(main):002:0>
```

Upon further investigation, I notice that it's crashing at this part of the code.

```
# hiredis-rb/lib/hiredis/connection.rb
module Hiredis
  begin
    require "hiredis/ext/connection"
    Connection = Ext::Connection
  rescue LoadError
    warn "WARNING: could not load hiredis extension, using (slower) pure Ruby implementation."
    require "hiredis/ruby/connection"
    Connection = Ruby::Connection
  end
end
```

So, I required the file `hiredis/ext/connection` and the error I get is the following error:

```
irb(main):001:0> require "hiredis/ext/connection"
LoadError: /home/***/projects/***/.gemset/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.1.0-static/hiredis-0.5.2/hiredis/ext/hiredis_ext.so: 
undefined symbol: redisReaderFree -
/home/***/projects/***/.gemset/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.1.0-static/hiredis-0.5.2/hiredis/ext/hiredis_ext.so
from /home/***/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
```

I'm using Ubuntu and latest stable version of Redis (2.8.18). How do I fix this? Thanks!

EDIT:

So after looking at the hiredis-rb page: https://github.com/redis/hiredis-rb, it says that I should do the following:

> To use hiredis with redis-rb, you need to require
>   redis/connection/hiredis before creating a new connection.

So I did a `require "redis/connection/hiredis"` on irb and then `require "hiredis"` and everything worked fine, no more warnings.

But now the warnings don't happen at all anymore now. I assumed that I'd need to `require "redis/connection/hiredis"` everytime for it to work but now it just works. So I dunno why it's not warning me anymore now. I thought calling `require "redis/connection/hiredis"` during that irb session was only for that session, not all succeeding sessions.

Comment: Do you have redis installed? `$ redis-cli --version`

Comment: When you run `$ gem install hiredis` what comes out?

Comment: Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
    Successfully installed hiredis-0.5.2
    Parsing documentation for hiredis-0.5.2
    Done installing documentation for hiredis after 0 seconds
    1 gem installed

Comment: Fresh out of ideas, sorry mate. i'm on osx.

Comment: @AJcodez Thanks for checking it out at least. I edited my post, added something at the last part. Some new info.